# Какой типа данных выбрать для MySQL

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, какой тип данных выбрать для 11-значного числа 000.12345678 с плавающей точкой для записи в таблицу SQL?

Comment: Вы сами же написали ответ внутри вопроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тебе подойдёт [DECIMAL Data Type Characteristics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) с парамемтрами:

```
DECIMAL(11,8)
```

Что означает, что оно будет хранить 11 цифр, 8 из которых будут после запятой.

Comment: А если предполагается, что не все числа будут с 8 цифрами после запятой? Например некоторые из них с двумя, но максимум с 8 цифрами

Comment: У тебя будет выделенная область хранения в данном случае, если ты не знаешь точно, какие данные будут храниться - это возможная проблема в будущем, так что лучше выяснить сразу. Если всё же выяснить точно не удаётся, то есть типы для хранения чисел с плавающей запятой FLOAT и DOUBLE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html, только нужно учесть, что при их использовании есть определённые ньюансы с точностью, если это не критично, лучше использовать именно их, так как вычислительные операции будут работать быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Приветствую! Используйте [**decimal**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) или [**float**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html)